# How to clear an ASP.NET listbox with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listbox

I'm trying to clear all of the items in an ASP.NET listbox via javascript, but sadly

```
document.getElementById("<%= lstNames.clientID %>").items.clear;
```

does not work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use jquery `document.getElementById("<%= lstNames.clientID %>").empty()`

or

```
document.getElementById("<%= lstNames.clientID %>").options.length = 0;
```

Comment: Don't you mean $('#lstNames').empty(); -- Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
document.getElementById("<%= lstNames.clientID %>").selectedIndex = -1; // will throw error on next if there are selected items
document.getElementById("<%= lstNames.clientID %>").options.length = 0;
```

or

`document.getElementById("<%= lstNames.clientID %>").innerHTML = "";`